# Unity: Nautilus folder opens in background

Tags: 12.04, unity, nautilus, configuration, directory

I am used to open a folder from the keyboard with a shortcut. The alternatives are:

- Use Unity Dash with the shortcut `SUPER` + `F` to open the Dash File Lens
- Open [Kupfer](http://engla.github.com/kupfer/) with the configured shortcut (`CTRL` + `ALT` + `SPACE`, in my case)

Then I type the name of the folder and press `ENTER` if it is selected.
However, the window that opens up is **not active** but in the background. I have to press `ALT` + `TAB` to bring it into foreground.
I use Ubuntu Precise (12.04.).

**Question:** How can I configure Ubuntu, Unity, Nautilus so newly opened windows become foreground immediately?

---

**Edit:** This behavior only happens when another application is already open such as GEdit. It does not happen when the only other selectable entity is the Desktop.

Comment: have you tried `super+1` which is my Home folder alignment no. in unity launcher panel , or try pressing `super` to get the icon number and try the command.

Comment: Since I use many different folders at different times having a shortcut for each in the panel is not an option. Nevertheless, I tried your suggestion and place my HOME folder there. The behavior is the same.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 (with unity):
Focus prevention level OFF fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **NOT** the default behaviour.Check the settings of *Focus and Raise Behaviour* in CompizConfig Settings Manager > General > General Options.(You may need to [install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) ccsm first).
[image: ccsm]

Comment: I can no longer reproduce the behavior. It might have been fixed in one of the kernel releases. Nevertheless I like to grant you the answer flag. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem is NOT solved by checking *Auto-Raise*, rather, by changing `Focus Prevention Level` from Low to **Off** in `ccsm`.